# Can't configure zabbix server action ssh operation

Tags: ssh, zabbix

Added public and private keys to zabbix server, checked if can manually connect to desired host.
But configured action returns "Failed to import public key: Access denied." every time it tries to connect via SSH.
Can't figure out what's wrong.
Host is already monitored via active agent and jmx.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out public key should be formatted from default way:
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
$key
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----

To "known hosts" way:
ssh-rsa $key

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).